# How to retrieve information on author of a youtube video from URL

Tags: youtube

We have a limited access to youtube in our organisation (it is banned by default, only several marcoms guys have exception). However, we would like employees to be able to watch the videos that have been posted by our official youtube account and keep the rest restricted. Is there any way how to filter the author of a video from URL so that we can add an exception to our company filter?

Comment: take a look at this [link](http://salman-w.blogspot.fr/2010/01/retrieve-youtube-video-title.html)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for me...it says it is unable to fetch URL/ID of the video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going a bit deeper into the link Fares provided, if you can use a GET request and parse JSON, you can use the API:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/

or more specifically:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries?csw=1

for example, the json for [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqKafI7Amd8) is :
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/hqKafI7Amd8?v=2&alt=json-in-script
snippet containing author:

```
"author":[{"name":{"$t":"TEDx Talks"},"uri":"$t":"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TEDxTalks"},"yt$userId":{"$t":"sT0YIqwnpJCM-mx7-gSA4Q"}}]
```

or, the xml is at this url:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/hqKafI7Amd8?v=2

however, the v2 api has been depreciated, so this might not work forever

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the script had the **https** case missed on regex, so i modified the script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#youtubeDataQuery').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var videoid = $('#youtubeVideoId').val();
           alert(videoid);
        var m;
        if (m = videoid.match(/^(http|https):\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/.*[?&]v=([^&]+)/i) || videoid.match(/^(http|https):\/\/youtu\.be\/([^?]+)/i)) {
          videoid = m[2];
          alert(videoid);
        }
        if (!videoid.match(/^[a-z0-9_-]{11}$/i)) {
          alert('Unable to parse Video ID/URL.');
          return;
        }
        $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + encodeURIComponent(videoid) + '?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=?',function(data) {

      var s = '';
      s += '<img src="' + data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url + '" width="' + data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].width + '" height="' + data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].height + '" alt="' + data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].yt$name + '" align="right"/>';
      s += '<b>Title:</b> ' + data.entry.title.$t + '<br/>';
      s += '<b>Author:</b> ' + data.entry.author[0].name.$t + '<br/>';
      s += '<b>Published:</b> ' + new Date(data.entry.published.$t).toLocaleDateString() + '<br/>';
      s += '<b>Duration:</b> ' + Math.floor(data.entry.media$group.yt$duration.seconds / 60) + ':' + (data.entry.media$group.yt$duration.seconds % 60) + ' (' + data.entry.media$group.yt$duration.seconds + ' seconds)<br/>';
      if (data.entry.gd$rating) {
        s += '<b>Rating:</b> ' + data.entry.gd$rating.average.toFixed(1) + ' out of ' + data.entry.gd$rating.max + ' (' + data.entry.gd$rating.numRaters + ' ratings)<br/>';
      }
      s += '<b>Statistics:</b> ' + data.entry.yt$statistics.favoriteCount + ' favorite(s); ' + data.entry.yt$statistics.viewCount + ' view(s)<br/>';
      s += '<br/>' + data.entry.media$group.media$description.$t.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') + '<br/>';
      s += '<br/><a href="' + data.entry.media$group.media$player.url + '" target="_blank">Watch on YouTube</a>';
      $('#youtubeDataOutput').html(s);
    });
      });
    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xuk4N/)